# How to choose from two connection strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

Good afternoon, I have encountered a problem to choose from two connection strings using C# and Linq to Entities. Currently I have two connection strings which are:

```
<add name="GameHutDBEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/GameHutModel.csdl|res://*/GameHutModel.ssdl|res://*/GameHutModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=EMMANUEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GameHutDB;user id=GameHutAdmin; password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="GameHutDBEntities2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/GameHutModel.csdl|res://*/GameHutModel.ssdl|res://*/GameHutModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=EMMANUEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GameHutDB;user id=test; password=1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have two roles which are Admin and Clerk. How can I allow the admin to login with the first connection string and the clerk will login with the second connection string?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257107/entity-framework-to-multiple-databases-same-schema-at-runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1257432/1583):

```
string connString;

if(IsAdmin(user))
    connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GameHutDBEntities1"];
else
    connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GameHutDBEntities2"];

using(EntityConnection con = new EntityConnection(connString))
{
  using (Entities context = new Entities(con))
  {
      // Some code here
  }
}
```

Where `IsAdmin` is a function taking a `user` and returning true if he is an admin and false if not.

Comment: I am working with three tier model, where do I need to put this code please? and thanks for answering my question!

Comment: @user1114676 - This would be in the data access layer, though I would pass the connection string (or a boolean indicating the user is an admin or not) through from the UI as a dependency (you _don't_ want to hard code a dependency on `ConfigurationManager` into your data access layer.

Comment: the configurationmanager is not recognized in the data layer, is there a way to use it in the data layer please?

Comment: @user1114676 - It is part of the `System.Configuration` namespace. You can add the assembly and import the namespace where you need to use it. But, I advise against it - you would be hard coding a dependency to configuration into your data access layer.

Comment: @user1114676 - Then you are doing something wrong. Are you sure your config has connection strings with the names you are using? Are you using the correct config?

Comment: i put the following code in the login page and it works fine but the problems is that when the user goes to another page, the connection string is not stored anymore. Do you know why please?

Comment: @user1114676 - Why should a different page know about code that isn't in it?

Comment: i need to store a connectionstring for the admin and another for the clerk. when the admin is logged, the admin connectionstring is used but when the admin goes to add a user the connection string is changed to default...

Comment: @user1114676 - You can store the connection string in a `Session` variable.

Comment: the problem is that i need to pass the connString in the datalayer in the connnection class. The session and application variables are not accessed in the data layer and the business layer. If it's possible i think i can solve the problem

Comment: @user1114676 - If your data layer was written to take a connection string as a parameter, I don't see the problem. You still use the data layer from the upper layers, no?

Comment: as i have two connection strings i need to store one of them in the connection class according to the role and keeps using it until the user logs off.

Comment: @user1114676 - You really need to ask another question about this issue. It is not really part of your original question and comments are not a way to do this.

Comment: you are very helpful so can I send you the source code please?

Comment: @user1114676 - No. That's no how we do things on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

```
var conn = new EntityConnection();
conn.StoreConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GameHutDBEntities2"];

this.Entities = new KurtDBEntities(conn);
```

Comment: I am working with three tier model, where do I need to put this code please? and thanks for answering my question! –

Comment: Whereever you are instantiaing your Entities just pass the connection as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, that one. Just pass the connection to the constructor.

Comment: See my edit, all code is C#. However, you need to make the logic if user is admin or not.