# How to target multiple databases with Entity Framework 6 for same data?

Tags: entity-framework-6, multiple-databases, redundancy

I was wondering whether it is possible to target multiple databases with EF6.

here i can see one can use two connections with two different db contexts. 
[Configure multiple database Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308378/configure-multiple-database-entity-framework-6)
but i want actually to save the same information to two different databases for the same request.
Databases can even be different like one is Oracle and other is SQL server.

Any idea for achieving this type of redundancy with Ef6?

Comment: So you want to basically call `SaveChanges()` once and have it save on two databases (potentially with different providers)?

Comment: yes exactly :) how can i do that properly?